# LINQ Query not pulling all records needed

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am having some trouble with a LINQ query.

This query creates a list of new objects based on entries from a repository. 
Here is the original query:

```
var accounts = (from a in entityRepository.Queryable<Account>()
                from l in a.ExternalLogins 
                select new
                {
                    a.ID,
                    FullName = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                    Status = a.Status == AccountStatus.Closed ? Enums.Status.Inactive : Enums.Status.Active,
                    Login = new
                    {   
                        ConnectionID = l.Connection.ID,
                        l.Connection.ConnectionType,
                        l.Identity    
                    },
                    a.AdminAccess,
                    a.Username,
                    a.Email
                }).ToList();
```

My issue is that not all `a` have an `a.ExternalLogins`. The query is not pulling those accounts because of the additional from statement `from l in a.ExternalLogins`. I tried modifying the query to:

```
 var accounts = (from a in entityRepository.Queryable<Account>() 
                 select new
                {
                    a.ID,
                    FullName = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                    Status = a.Status == AccountStatus.Closed ? Enums.Status.Inactive : Enums.Status.Active,
                    Login = (from l in a.ExternalLogins
                    select new
                    {   
                      ConnectionID = l.Connection.ID,
                      l.Connection.ConnectionType,
                      l.Identity    
                    }),
                    a.AdminAccess,
                    a.Username,
                    a.Email
                }).ToList();
```

But I am getting a 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' exception.
From looking up that exception, I am guessing that the reason is because both `Account` and `Connection` have the field `ID`.

Am I headed in the right direction with this? Do I chase down this exception, or is my query not correct?

I apologize if this is trivial; I'm new to LINQ queries, and my google skills have failed me at this point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a left outer join in Linq, add a `DefaultIfEmpty()` call and check for null in the results:

```
var accounts = (from a in entityRepository.Queryable<Account>()
            from l in a.ExternalLogins.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            select new
            {
                a.ID,
                FullName = a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                Status = a.Status == AccountStatus.Closed ? Enums.Status.Inactive : Enums.Status.Active,
                Login = (l == null) ? null : new
                {   
                    ConnectionID = l.Connection.ID,
                    l.Connection.ConnectionType,
                    l.Identity    
                },
                a.AdminAccess,
                a.Username,
                a.Email
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That totally makes sense, but when I tried that, I get the exception 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' that says, "Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]" with the inner exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @GrapeJelly You might consider adding some of the `nhibernate` tags to the question since the above works in "general" LINQ.

Comment: @Ivan Steven Added! Sorry, I didn't know that was playing a factor to this specifically.

Comment: Update: I found that there was a record in my database that had `NULL` as the value for `Status`. This caused the exception to be thrown. When fixing this record, the query works! Thank you @stuartd!